# PHP artisan is not recognized

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to learn Laravel-The PHP Framework and wanted to use artisan.
I already installed Laravel globally and also created my first project but every time I run `php artisan` it doesnt recognize the command. I opened git on my project directory and sill not recognized.

It gives me this error:

```
$ php artisan
PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\--------\Desktop\Project\Laravel\firstProject/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\--------\Desktop\Project\Laravel\firstProject\artisan on line 18

Warning: require(C:\Users\--------\Desktop\Project\Laravel\firstProject/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\--------\Desktop\Project\Laravel\firstProject\artisan on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\--------\Desktop\Project\Laravel\firstProject/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\--------\Desktop\Project\Laravel\firstProject\artisan:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\--------\Desktop\Project\Laravel\firstProject\artisan on line 18

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\--------\Desktop\Project\Laravel\firstProject/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\--------\Desktop\Project\Laravel\firstProject\artisan:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\--------\Desktop\Project\Laravel\firstProject\artisan on line 18
```

I tried downloading PHP manually or use the PHP from XAMPP but no changes.
I used `php v8.0.2` and `composer v2.0.11`

Comment: You shouldn't install laravel globally(unless you mean the laravel installer). If you do mean the laravel installer then can you share the sequence of commands including the one to create the project?

Comment: So. I just need to install laravel on my project folder?

Comment: Check https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#your-first-laravel-project Personally I prefer the laravel installer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't install Laravel globally.
Go through this link:
[How to Install Laravel on Ubuntu 20.04](https://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-ubuntu-20-04/)

Comment: Thank you. I just followed the installation guide on the laravel website thats why I installed it globally. It seems it works now. thanks

Comment: Nice to hear. Happy coding.

Comment: just wanna ask tho. when im coding laravel on VS code. theres no colors on the code and theres no recommendation when im coding. do you know what is the name of that and how to download it in VS code?

Comment: THere are bunch of packages. Go through this link: https://devdojo.com/bobbyiliev/8-awesome-vs-code-extensions-for-laravel-developers